# How do I manage that the different nodes in a distributed scheduler picks unique events?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, scheduler, job-scheduling, distributed-system

I have a distributed job scheduler running on three machines which picks events from a database (elastic search).

The problem that I am facing is sometimes all the nodes pick the same events. That is unnecessary load on the system resources.

What I want to do is I want to implement a mechanism so that each node that is part of the distributed scheduler should pick unique events.

I am exploring the following options:

1. Add the node ip in the job itself and while fetching the data from elastic search, I can pass the node id also. (This is the current implementation I am using).
2. I have tried to explore zookeeper to accomplish the same but I am not sure whether it is possible using zookeeper.

Can anyone help me for moving in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 1):

Is not wrong use a backend to store jobs but it could become a bottleneck if the number of transactions is very high (> 1k tps).

For distributed scheduling you need to solve two things:

1. one and only one worker should take a task (your related problem).
2. if a worker fail running a task (e.g. out of memory, restart, ...) the task should back to persistence.

To solve both problems easilly with a typical backend you can add two fields:

```
State :: { PENDING, WORKING, DONE }
LastUpdate :: DateTime
```

To solve the former problem you must query and update one `PENDING` record atomically (i.e. in the same transaction):

```
@Transactional
public Optional<Task> getTaskToWorkOnIfAny() {
    Optional<Task> task = myBackend.getOnePendingTask();
    if(task.isPresent())
        // update task, I'm working on it!
        myBackend.updateTask(task.get(), WORKING, new DateTime());
    return task;
}
```

then, work on it as usual.

To solve the later problem, simply check when a task is `WORKING` too much time (if your tasks are very long you could add a `ping` updating the field).

Should I write `try/catch` to move `WORKING` to `PENDING` if my task fail. Well, you could but if the system really crash your task will be `WORKING` anyway so, you should follow my previous strategy.

NOTE: to take in account the whole problem you only must to follow the previous code where `getTaskToWorkOnIfAny` is something like `SELECT * FROM task WHERE state = 'PENDING' OR (state = 'WORKING' AND lastUpdate < yesterday()`. Nothing more.

Comment: I agree with the approach you have suggested. But my problem is a little different. Correct me if I am wrong. Suppose that I have two nodes: node1 and node2 which are running my scheduler. I will run the same sql query (you mentioned above) on both the nodes. In this case, it is possible that both nodes will fetch common tasks (lets say node1 fetched tasks from id 1 -100 and node2 fetched the tasks from id 20-120. I want to avoid this. I want to do this: node1 fetches task 1-60 and node2 61-120. There should not be any common tasks between the tasks fetched by both the nodes. Is that possible?

Comment: And second thing, to make the operation atomic in a distributed environment, I will have to use distributed locks using redis (or some other tool). If each scheduler takes up different tasks, we can avoid using locks.

Comment: No, only the `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: _"it is possible that both nodes will fetch common tasks"_ no, as I said, one task will be taken by one and only one worker.